# Count objects in array ignoring null

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm very junior, excuse me if it isn't an appropriate.

Trying to count the objects in an array, ignoring null.
This is my code so far:

```
    function countTheObjects (arr) {

        let count = 0;

          for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
             if (typeof arr[i] === 'object') {
               count++;
             }
             if (arr[i] === null) {
               count--;
             }


           }
         return count;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

All these codes you guys have given me return exactly the same error mine does. These are the tests the code has to pass:

```
describe('countTheObjects', function () {
  it('returns the count of objects inside an array of random data types', function () {
    expect(countTheObjects([])).to.equal(0);
    expect(countTheObjects([1, 3, 4, 5])).to.equal(0);
    expect(countTheObjects([1, 3, 4, 5, 'foo'])).to.equal(0);
    expect(countTheObjects([1, 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo'])).to.equal(3);
    expect(countTheObjects([1, [], 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo'])).to.equal(3);
    expect(countTheObjects([1, [], null, 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo'])).to.equal(3);
    expect(countTheObjects([1, {}, [], null, null, 'foo', 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo'])).to.equal(4);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why do you decrease?..

Comment: Because it will add one up when finds a null, as is identified as an object? Am I wrong? Thanks for aswering and being so quick.

Comment: **Add your failing test arrays to the question.** You should have done that from the start.

Comment: do `console.log(typeof [])`. Your tests are expecting a wrong result. `Arrays` in Javascript are `Objects`

Comment: You picked a working, but suboptimal answer.

Comment: @VisualXZ: Have you tested my answer?

Comment: @VisualXZ Run his tests with your answer.

Comment: I even added all your tests to my answer.

Comment: Use a reliable `isObject` type detection method of your choice. Filter the given array by this method. Get the length of the filtered result ...

Comment: Marking this Q as duplicate and linking to "why is typeof null 'object'" is not quite right since the OP does not struggle with this matter; but the provided example code shows that the tests exclusively expect direct instances of `Object`. Thus the OP really does look for a reliable type detection method that distinguishes real `Object` instances from all the other instances like e.g. `Array`, `RegExp`, `Date` etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are doing unnecessary decrement. You should just move null check to the first if. typeof [] is also 'object'

```
function countTheObjects (arr) {
let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (typeof arr[i] === 'object' && arr[i] !== null && !Array.isArray(arr[i]) ) {
       count++;
     }
   }
 return count;
}
```

Comment: Still gives me the same error .   1) countTheObjects
       returns the count of objects inside an array of random data types:

      AssertionError: expected 4 to equal 3
      + expected - actual

      -4
      +3

      at Context.<anonymous> (test/5-objects.test.js:227:69)

Comment: What is the actual text of the task for these tests? I think there is some deeper issue with it. Maybe counting objects inside nested array or something like that.

Comment: This function takes an array of different data types. It should return a count of the number of objects in the array.

  NB, think carefully about how to test if something is an object! Arrays are technically types of objects in JavaScript, as is the value null. However these should not be counted.

Comment: The issue was that array is also object. I changed code so now it should be correct.

Comment: All done now. Thank you very very much. I see what you meant there.

Comment: `typeof arr[i] === 'object' && arr[i] !== null` can be shortened to `arr[i] instanceof Object`, see my answer.

Comment: @GrayFox ... what happens if the array contains yet other object types than just instances of `Object` and/or `Array`?

Comment: @VisualXZ: This answer doesn't pass in case your array is `var array = [1, {}, [], null, null, 'foo', 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']`. It returns `4`.

Comment: It returns 4 and there are 4 objects
@Peter Seliger For this particular task the case is correct and verbose. Of course in real case we must check the instance but OP is just learning how to code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong because `typeof null === "object"`

```js
function countTheObjects (arr) {
  let count = 0;
  
  arr.forEach(e => {
    if (typeof e === "object" && e !== null) {
      count++;
    }
  });
  
  return count;
}
    
    
alert(countTheObjects([
  1, 2, 3, null, null, 5, 6, null, {}, {}, {}
]));
```

Comment: Nope, still same error.

Comment: He wants to count `object`. 1, 2, 3, 5, 6 are not objects.

Comment: This is not matter, it is easy to add one more chech for any type you want. My example shows how to avoid logic errors like in authors code.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```js
let arr = []
console.log(typeof arr) // 'object'
```

**Your test expectations are wrong.**

`Array` has `typeof` `'object'` in Javascript.

**If you want to make sure arrays are not counted**, use `Array.isArray(arr)`. You can also simplify your code considerably using `instanceof` instead of `typeof`:

```js
function countTheObjects(arr) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(countTheObjects([]) === 0);
console.log(countTheObjects([1, 3, 4, 5]) === 0);
console.log(countTheObjects([1, 3, 4, 5, 'foo']) === 0);
console.log(countTheObjects([1, 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']) === 3);
console.log(countTheObjects([1, [], 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']) === 3);
console.log(countTheObjects([1, [], null, 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']) === 3);
console.log(countTheObjects([1, {}, [], null, null, 'foo', 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']) === 4);
```

Comment: I realised that, that I'm count ++ and then --, but it was the only thing I could think of to get rid of null being counted.

Comment: Add the test arrays to your question.

Comment: @connexo ... what happens if the array contains yet other object types than just instances of `Object` and/or `Array`?

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to decrease the count when an element is `null`.
- Check for `!== null && typeof === "object"`.
- `null` is a primitive, however in Javascript `typeof null === 'object'`.

```js
function countTheObjects(arr) {
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== null && typeof arr[i] === 'object') {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(countTheObjects([5, null, {}, "", null, {}, ""]));
```

Using the function `reduce` from ES6:

```js
function countTheObjects(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((count, obj) => count + (obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object'), 0);
}

console.log(countTheObjects([null, {}, 5, "", null, {}, ""]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this

```js
var input = [
  [1, 2, 3], {
    key: 'some value'
  },
  null, null, 5, 6, null, {}
];

console.log(input.reduce((prev, current) => {
  return current !== null ? prev + 1 : prev
}, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple implementation:

```js
let dataArray = [1, {}, [], null, null, 'foo', 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']
let countNotNulls = arr => arr.filter( el => el !== null );
console.log(countNotNulls(dataArray).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

A reliable approach for answering the OP's question boils down to ... just find or implement the correct/matching type detection method. Then, make use of this method as callback function of the `filter` method that filters the provided array of different/mixed types. Read the `length` property of the filtered result.

A generic implementation of an `isObject` check might look like this ...

```
function isObject(type) {
  return (!!type && (typeof type === 'object'));
};
```

... but it will let pass any value/type that neither is `null` nor `undefined` nor of any other primitive type. Thus it will also let pass other objects like instances of `Array`, `RegExp`, `Date` etc.

The OP wants to test for direct instances of `Object`. A solution then might look like the following provided ...

```js
function isObjectObject(type) {
  return (/^\[object\s+Object\]$/).test(Object.prototype.toString.call(type));
}

function getObjectCount(list) {
  return Array.from(list).filter(isObjectObject).length;
}

console.log("(getObjectCount([]) === 0) ? ", (getObjectCount([]) === 0));
console.log("(getObjectCount([1, 3, 4, 5]) === 0) ? ", (getObjectCount([1, 3, 4, 5]) === 0));
console.log("(getObjectCount([1, 3, 4, 5, 'foo']) === 0) ? ", (getObjectCount([1, 3, 4, 5, 'foo']) === 0));
console.log("(getObjectCount([1, 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']) === 3) ? ", (getObjectCount([1, 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']) === 3));
console.log("(getObjectCount([1, [], 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']) === 3) ? ", (getObjectCount([1, [], 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']) === 3));
console.log("(getObjectCount([1, [], null, 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']) === 3) ? ", (getObjectCount([1, [], null, 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']) === 3));
console.log("(getObjectCount([1, {}, [], null, null, 'foo', 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']) === 4) ? ", (getObjectCount([1, {}, [], null, null, 'foo', 3, 4, 5, {}, {}, {}, 'foo']) === 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```